# How do i restart IDLE in the code?

Tags: python

At the bottom where it asks if you would like to restart the program, I need to find a way to restart it.  I've tried functions and a while loop but they have all failed.

```
continues=1

while continues==(1):   
    words=["adduct","carpet","garlic","guitar","detail","catkin","choral","longer","lizard","magpie","lawyer","patchy"]
    import random
    import time
    import sys
    import os

    letterr=0
    left=6
    guesses_left=10
    correct=["_","_","_","_","_","_"]

    chosen_word=(random.choice(words))
    letters=list(chosen_word)

    for letter in chosen_word:
            if letter:
             letterr+=1

    print(letters)
    print("The number of letters in the word is:", letterr)

    while guesses_left >= 1:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("")
            guess=input("Guess a letter of the word. ")
            print("")
            time.sleep(1)
            if guess in("abcdefghijklmnopjrstuvxywz"):

                    if guess in(letters):

                            if guess in(correct):
                                time.sleep(0.5)
                                print("You have already guessed this letter. ")
                                guesses_left=guesses_left - 1
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print("You have",guesses_left, "guesses left.")
                                time.sleep(1) 
                                print("Letters:"," ".join(correct))
                            else:
                                guesses_left=guesses_left-1
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print("You have succesfully guessed a letter in the word. ")
                                print("")
                                time.sleep(0.5)
                                print("You have",guesses_left, "guesses left.")
                                print("")
                                index=chosen_word.index(guess)
                                correct[index]=guess
                                time.sleep(0.5) 
                                print("Letters:"," ".join(correct))



                    else:
                            guesses_left=guesses_left-1
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            print("")
                            print("You have incorrectly guessed a letter in the word. ")
                            print("")
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            print("You have",guesses_left,"guesses left. ")
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            print("")
                            print("Letters:"," ".join(correct))



                    if guesses_left==(0):
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            print("")
                            print("Game over, you have not won")
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            print("")
                            print("The word was:",wordd,)
                            restart0=0
                            while restart0==(0):
                                    restart=input("Would you like to play again? ")
                                    if restart in("yes","yeah","Yes","Yeah"):
                                            restart0=0
                                            continues=1
                                    if restart in("no","nope","No","Nope"):
                                            restart0=0
                                            print("")
                                            time.sleep(0.5)
                                            print("Thank you for playing")
                                            print("")
                                            time.sleep(2)
                                            quit()
                                    if restart not in("no","nope","No","Nope","yes","yeah","Yes","Yeah"):
                                            restart0=1
                                            print("")
                                            time.sleep(1)
                                            print("Enter a valid answer")
                                            print("")


            else:
                    print("Please only enter letters! ")
                    guesses_left=guesses_left - 1
                    print("")
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print("There are",left,"letters left in the word. ")
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print("")
                    print("Letters:"," ".join(correct))

            if ("_") not in(correct):
                    print("")
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print("You have won! ")
                    print("")
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    restart1=input("Would you like to play again? ")
                    restart2=0
                    while restart2==(0):
                            if restart1 in("yes","yeah","Yes","Yeah"):
                                restart2=1
                                os.execv(idek, sys.argv)
                            if restart1 in("no","nope","No","Nope"):
                                restart2=1
                                print("")
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print("Thank you for playing ")
                                print("")
                                time.sleep(1)
                                quit()
                            if restart1 not in("no","nope","No","Nope","yes","yeah","Yes","Yeah"):
                                restart2=0
                                time.sleep(1)
                                print("")
                                print("Enter a valid answer")
```

Comment: Please don't post a link to your code. Include your code in your question.

Comment: Surely it's not IDLE that you want to restart, but your script.

Comment: Your whole program seems to *already* be in a `while continues==(1):` loop.  Wouldn't it restart if `continues` was set to `1` when it hit the end of the loop (and quit if `continue` wasn't `1`)?  Also, you *probably* want to get the `input()` for `restart1` *inside* the `while` loop.

Comment: Some tips: the `len()` function works on lists and strings and lots of other things (and you seem to already know it since you have pre-filled `correct`), do not put your `import` lines *inside* the loop, `continues==(1)` can be `continues==1` you don't need so many extra `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you have an error with

```
os.exec(idek, sys.argv)
```

"idek" is not defined anywhere.

Second your code is a bit too complicated in terms of restart. You could enclose everything in a while loop which will run forever unless you give it the command to end. For example

```
while True:
# All of your logic for the guessing game goes here.
# at the end, ask the user if they want to restart.
# If they answer 'yes','yeah', etc, do nothing, the loop will automatically
# restart and reset all of your values.
# Else, do a break and the loop will end thus ending your game.
```

I hope this helps you in figuring out what you need to do.

Sidenote: Personally I don't agree with using

```
while True:
```

but for a small project like this it's fine.

Comment: So is True a variable or a function?

Comment: @jamiewood: `True` and `False` are boolean values.  See: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values

Comment: @archangel When the user is asked whether they want to play again the script does not start from the complete beginning, but from "while guesses_left >= 1:" do you know why this is?

Comment: @jamiewood 'True' is a Python keyword, same with 'break'. Here is a [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keyword-list) that will show you Python keywords. These are reserved by the language and you cannot use them anywhere besides for their intended use i.e you cannot have a variable called 'break'.

Comment: @jamiewood: What if they won, but still had some guesses left?  What would `while guesses_left >= 1:` evaluate to?

Comment: @jamiewood: I meant, you should set `guesses_left = 0` so that it breaks out of the loop.